# How do I register logging driver for docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I'm trying to use Amazon CloudWatch Logs logging driver as described in [this doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/logging/awslogs/).

But I get following error when I launch my container

```
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 1769b857d0ed51cf30b1c160485c9eb05f68ab07a84eaf861893d9d55e6139c4: 
Failed to initialize logging driver: 
Failed to get logging factory: logger: no log driver named 'awslogs' is registered
```

How do I register driver for docker ? Shall I modify docker's systemd script or something ?

Comment: This question is better suited for http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Thomasleveil I agree. But to my surprise there are less than 600 questions for docker compared to almost 9000 here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted bug on docker's github and got a reply that awslogs was not added until 1.9.0.

And according to [this issue](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/19392) AWS CloudWatch support seems to be broken in the latest version of Docker.